# SQL Server 2008 Multi-db stored procedure: The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, multi-database

I am trying to write a stored procedure for SQL Server 2008. It is for a migration tool that migrates data from one database to another.

I want to get all records from the old database that aren't yet present in the new database. For that end I use the stored procedure below. But I get the error

> The multi-part indentifier could not
>   be bound

while executing the stored procedure. What can I do to make this work?

Here is the SP:

```
SELECT *
FROM Measurement_device
WHERE Measurement_device.Department_Code = '99'
  AND mir.dbo.Gages.Gage_code != Device_Number
```

Comment: Look at the `Merge` statement for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have the `mir.dbo.Gages.Gage_code` condition when that table is not referenced in the FROM clause. Try something like this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Measurement_device m
    LEFT JOIN mir.dbo.Gages g ON g.Gage_code = m.Device_Number
WHERE m.Department_Code = '99'
    AND g.Gage_code IS NULL -- where the gage_code/device_number does not already exist in mir database
```